# Pausing after debugging command line application in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, command-line

Is there a way short of writing a seperate batch file or adding a system call to pause or getch or a breakpoint right before the end of the main function to keep a command window open after a command line application has finished running?

Put differently, is there a way in the project properties to run another command after running the target path? If my program is "foo.exe", something equivalent to a batch file containing

```
@foo
@pause
```

Edit: added "or a getch or a breakpoint"

Answer (score 5):

As you may know, at least in the C# project system, pressing Ctrl-F5 will add a "press any key to continue" to the end.  But this doesn't run under the debugger, so I endorse the prior answer that said 'put a breakpoint at the end of main'.

Answer (score 3):

If running in the debugger (going by the title of your question), I just put a breakpoint at the closing brace in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

In C++

```
#include <conio.h>

// .. Your code

int main()
{
  // More of your code

  // Tell the user to press a key 
  getch();      // Get one character from the user (i.e a keypress)

  return 0;

}
```

If you are in a batch file, the command "pause" outputs "Press any key to continue" and waits for a keypress.

Answer (score 0):

If one has access to source code,

1.) Will adding a getch()  added just before main ends, not puase the application executuion, while displaying the console applications console window as it was?
Basically add any code which waits on a keyboard input

-AD